# Simulating the trajectory of a particle from rest under gravity

Tags: python, simulation, physics, particles

I hope you can help! I need to show the trajectory of a particle that is under gravity of `g = -9.81` m/s<sup>2</sup> and time step of `dt = 0.05` sec, where the position and velocity of the particle are:

1. `x_1 = x_0 + v_x1 * dt`
2. `y_1 = y_0 + v_y1 * dt`
3. `v_x1 = v_x0`
4. `v_y1 = v_y0 + g * dt`

This is what I should achieve:
[image]
This is what I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1, figsize=(12,12))
ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.set_ylim(0,50)
ax.set_title('Boom --- Weeee! --- Ooof')

r = np.array([0.,0.,15.,30.])
g = -9.81
dt = 0.05
y = 0
x = 0
while y > 0:
    plt.plot(x_1,y_2,':', ms=2)
    x_1 = v_x1 * dt
    y_1 = v_y1 * dt
    v_x1 = v_x0
    v_y1 = v_y0 + g * dt
```

This doesn't produce an image only the `plt.figure` stated in the beginning, I've tried to integrate the `r` vector into the loop but I can't figure out how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code that I believe gives you the result you desire (you may want to choose different initial velocity values):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up our plot surface
plt.figure(1, figsize=(12,12))
ax = plt.subplot()
# ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect='equal')
# ax.set_ylim(0,50)
ax.set_title('Boom --- Weeee! --- Ooof')

# Initial conditions
g = -9.81
dt = 0.05
y = 0
x = 0
v_x = 5
v_y = 5

# Create our lists that will store our data points
points_x = []
points_y = []

while True:

    # Add the current position of our projectile to our data
    points_x.append(x)
    points_y.append(y)

    # Move our projectile along
    x += v_x * dt
    y += v_y * dt

    # If our projectile falls below the X axis (y < 0), end the simulation
    if y < 0:
        break

    # Update our y velocity per gravity
    v_y = v_y + g * dt

# Plot our data
ax.plot(points_x, points_y)

# Show the plot on the screen
plt.show()
```

I'm sorry if I could have made fewer changes.  Here are the substantive ones I can think of:

- You weren't using the `r` value you computed, so  got rid of it, along with the import of numpy that was then no longer needed.
- I took out calls you made explicitly size your plot.  You're better off letting the plot library decide upon the bounds of the plot for you
- I don't know if there's another way to do it, but I've always supplied data to the plotting library as arrays of points rather than by providing the points one at a time.  So here, I collect up all of the x and y coordinates into two lists while running the simulation, and then add those arrays to the plot at the end to plot the data.
- The `x_0` vs `x_1`, etc., got confusing for me.  I didn't see any reason to keep track of multiple position and velocity values, so I reduced the code down to using just one set of positions and velocities, `x`, `y`, `v_x` and `v_y`.
- See the comments for more info

Result:  [image: resulting plot]

Comment: Oh I see now what you were saying! Great answer. Also x_0 and x_1 are not really positions, it's just a physicist notation so I guess he adapted the notation to the code

Comment: @Callister - If you want points rather than a line, I'll leave that as an exercise for you to figure out.  I frankly don't know why we get a line here rather than distinct points.  I haven't done a lot with the plotting library.  Whatever I get on my first try is usually enough for me as I just want to get a basic idea of what my data looks like.

Comment: ax.plot(points_x, points_y, 'o') to get points instead of line. Line is the default line style